# Data Table Sorting Issue

Tags: c#, datetime, gridview, sharepoint-2010, datatable

I have been fighting with a wiered yet simple problem.

I have a Data table with some fields, one of the field is storing a datetime variable.

Then I use that data table to populate the grid view. Now I want to sort the values by default by that date field.

Problem :  1/2/2012 12:00:00 AM (I dont want tht Time portion in the grid view, I tried using with a string field but that is affecting my sorting).

Plz help me with this, I know this might be a simple one!!

Comment: are you using DataGridViewCellStyle.Format Property?

Comment: You can override the `compare()` method of the class you are putting in your data table and handle that

Comment: have you mady the dataTables yourself?

Comment: @Jithu - Is this web-app (asp.net) or winform?

Comment: @All Sorry for this late reply, Actually this is a SharePoint application, Where I am getting the Data Table on the fly using a CAML query (for retrieving data from a list) The date field is thr in the List itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily. If its a bound field in gridview, simply use

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="Your_Date_Column" dataformatstring="{0:MMMM d, yyyy}" htmlencode="false" />
```

Htmlencode property is must and it should be false.

Comment: Hi Anand, Sorry this is not a asp.net, @All Sorry for this late reply, Actually this is a SharePoint application, Where I am getting the Data Table on the fly using a CAML query (for retrieving data from a list) The date field is thr in the List itself.